# Serializing list of objects into json array list

Tags: python, json

My object is implemented like this:

```
class TestLog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_name = "Unknown"
        self.test_package = "Unknown"
        self.test_status = "Unknown"
        self.device = "Unknown"
        self.test_start_time = -1
        self.test_end_time = -1
        self.ran_times = 1
        self.error_messages = list()

    def __dict__(self):
        test_log_dict = dict()
        test_log_dict["test_name"] = self.test_name
        test_log_dict["test_package"] = self.test_package
        test_log_dict["test_status"] = self.test_status
        test_log_dict["device"] = self.device
        test_log_dict["test_start_time"] = self.test_start_time
        test_log_dict["test_end_time"] = self.test_end_time
        test_log_dict["ran_times"] = self.ran_times
        test_log_dict["error_messages"] = self.error_messages
        return test_log_dict
```

And I can turn it into JSON like that:

```
import json

log1 = TestLog()
log2 = TestLog()
json_dump1 = json.dumps(log1.__dict__())
json_dump2 = json.dumps(log2.__dict__())
```

And output is - 2 separate json objects:

log1:

```
{
    "test_name": "Unknown",
    "test_package": "Unknown",
    "test_status": "Unknown",
    "device": "Unknown",
    "test_start_time": -1,
    "test_end_time": -1,
    "ran_times": 1,
    "error_messages": []
}
```

log2:

```
{
    "test_name": "Unknown",
    "test_package": "Unknown",
    "test_status": "Unknown",
    "device": "Unknown",
    "test_start_time": -1,
    "test_end_time": -1,
    "ran_times": 1,
    "error_messages": []
}
```

I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE THIS RESULT:

```
{
    "test_results": [
        {
            "test_name": "Unknown",
            "test_package": "Unknown",
            "test_status": "Unknown",
            "device": "Unknown",
            "test_start_time": -1,
            "test_end_time": -1,
            "ran_times": 1,
            "error_messages": []
        },
        {
            "test_name": "Unknown",
            "test_package": "Unknown",
            "test_status": "Unknown",
            "device": "Unknown",
            "test_start_time": -1,
            "test_end_time": -1,
            "ran_times": 1,
            "error_messages": []
        }
    ]
}
```

But this approach doesn't work for me:

```
    log_dict = dict()
    log_dict.update({"test_results": [json_dump1, json_dump2]})
    list_dump = json.dumps(log_dict)
```

Because this happens:

{"test_results": ["{\"test_name\": \"Unknown\", \"test_package\": \"Unknown\", \"test_status\": \"Unknown\", \"device\": \"Unknown\", \"test_start_time\": -1, \"test_end_time\": -1, \"ran_times\": 1, \"error_messages\": []}", "{\"test_name\": \"Unknown\", \"test_package\": \"Unknown\", \"test_status\": \"Unknown\", \"device\": \"Unknown\", \"test_start_time\": -1, \"test_end_time\": -1, \"ran_times\": 1, \"error_messages\": []}"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.dumps` returns a string, so you are essentially appending strings to `log_dict['test_results']`.

Instead, create the whole dictionary as a whole and then convert it to a json string in one go:

```
log_dict = dict()
log_dict.update({"test_results": [log1.__dict__(), log2.__dict__()]})
list_dump = json.dumps(log_dict)
print(list_dump)

# {
#       "test_results": [{
#       "device": "Unknown",
#       "error_messages": [],
#       "test_status": "Unknown",
#       "test_start_time": -1,
#       "ran_times": 1,
#       "test_package": "Unknown",
#       "test_name": "Unknown",
#       "test_end_time": -1
#   }, {
#       "device": "Unknown",
#       "error_messages": [],
#       "test_status": "Unknown",
#       "test_start_time": -1,
#       "ran_times": 1,
#       "test_package": "Unknown",
#       "test_name": "Unknown",
#       "test_end_time": -1
#   }]
# }
```

By the way, you don't even need to implement `__dict__` if that is all you want to achieve. The default `__dict__` method already does it for you, and can be invoked by calling `vars` on the object:

```
import json

class TestLog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_name = "Unknown"
        self.test_package = "Unknown"
        self.test_status = "Unknown"
        self.device = "Unknown"
        self.test_start_time = -1
        self.test_end_time = -1
        self.ran_times = 1
        self.error_messages = list()


log1 = TestLog()
log2 = TestLog()


log_dict = dict()
log_dict.update({"test_results": [vars(log1), vars(log2)]})
list_dump = json.dumps(log_dict)

print(list_dump)

# {
#       "test_results": [{
#       "device": "Unknown",
#       "error_messages": [],
#       "test_status": "Unknown",
#       "test_start_time": -1,
#       "ran_times": 1,
#       "test_package": "Unknown",
#       "test_name": "Unknown",
#       "test_end_time": -1
#   }, {
#       "device": "Unknown",
#       "error_messages": [],
#       "test_status": "Unknown",
#       "test_start_time": -1,
#       "ran_times": 1,
#       "test_package": "Unknown",
#       "test_name": "Unknown",
#       "test_end_time": -1
#   }]
# }
```

Same result achieved with a simpler class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, since you need a dictionary as value, but you're storing the json string representing the serialized dictionary instead.

I would do this:

```
log_dict = {"test_results": [log1.__dict__(), log2.__dict__()]})
```

and if `log1` and `log2` must be frozen before, make a copy of the dicts

```
log1_dict = log1.__dict__().copy()
log2_dict = log2.__dict__().copy()
```

then:

```
log_dict = {"test_results": [log1_dict, log2_dict]})
```